# Backup a System via scp

Tags: centos, backup

I want to backup my System remotely. Can I jsut copy / via scp to get a working image of my System, or could this be a problem?

The System is a CentOS7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't just do that and get a working system.

Answer (score 1):

SCP, no, as Iain said. But you can use ssh and dd to do this:

For each disk to back up:

```
ssh root@host.to.backup "dd if=/dev/sdX | gzip -c" > host.to.backup.sdX.img.gz
```

Beware of changes to the disk while copying.

Comment: I C, so when im trying to backup the system with a single harddrive I have to do it on my local computer and connect to remote as follows:ssh user@remote "dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 -" | dd of=image.gz right?